# AppStream problems found "Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml" on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: apt, gnome-software, appstream

I have researched this, and there are no other entries on the internet that I can find with this problem, so posting here.  It may be that the wording in 17.04 is different leading to no hits.  But anyway, here it is...

I'm getting this error when trying to update my software on Ubuntu 17.04:

```
AppStream system cache was updated, but problems were found: 
Metadata files have errors: /var/cache/app-info/xmls/fwupd.xml
```

I have performed (all with `sudo`):

```
apt-get clean
apt-get update
appstreamcli --version (shows 0.10.6)
appstreamcli refresh --force
```

Then I went to the **System > Software and Updates** tab, selected **other**, then **Select Best Server**.  Did that, it set to `http://mirror.atlantic.net/ubuntu`, but I'm still getting problem.

Then ran:

```
appstreamcli refresh --force
suso apt-get upgrade
sudo appstreamcli refresh
```

Still getting the same error.

Any suggestion on how to clear up this issue?

Comment: I think the problem is that for some reason fwupd.xml can't be deleted...the directory `/var/cache/app-info`  needs to be deleted to refresh, but when there is still a file left in it, rmdir fails. I'm not sure. I ran into problems when completely removing gnome-software and dependencies (which include appstream)--the process couldn't complete because fwupd.xml remained in /var/cache/app-info/xmls. I don't know why that one file would persist, there is a [deb bug report here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=868465)...

Comment: Again not really sure about any of this or how to fix it--unless you just want to get rid of gnome-software altogether. If you don't use gnome-software/"Ubuntu Software" (I personally have no use for it at all), you don't need appinfo, and in that case I would just force removal of /var/cache/app-info/